# Default Criteria For Active Record

Tags: yii

I have a following question about the best practice for ActiveRecord usage.

My case:
I have a User model which is a normal `CActiveRecord`.
In many cases I want to have lists of "active" users, defined in the database by WHERE condition "is_active = 1". Besides I want functions `find()`, `findByAttributes()`, `findByPk()` etc. to return the result only if the user is active (for example in "Password request" scenario).

I can always apply this WHERE condition explicitly before using `find()` functions but I'm searching a way to implement it with less code.

I came to the idea of creating a child class called UserActive and change its constructor like this:

```
function __construct($scenario='insert') {
    parent::__construct($scenario);

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = "is_active = 1";
    $this->setDbCriteria($criteria);
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good practice to do this (Since `CActiveRecord`'s constructor asks **"Do NOT override the constructor unless it is absolutely necessary!**"). Can anyone give advices for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your model.

```
public function defaultScope() {
    return array(
               'condition'=>'is_active = 1',
            );

}
```

Or define other scope
[Yii - using relations with scopes defined in the relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315079/yii-using-relations-with-scopes-defined-in-the-relation)

Comment: check near return array end parenthesis remove curly bracket

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you should never override `__construct()`.
You can use model scopes for that. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes